# Unable to push complete backend data in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I want to push all the  backend data into the firebase without using foreach().Here is my data
**Json Data**

```
[{"_id":"5459beb12b7aedb40e000003",
    "vendorId":"prem123",
    "vendorName":"karn prem",
    "vendorContactNo":7897798789779},
{"_id":"545b3523bfc687100c000002",
  "vendorId":"wfwf",
 "vendorName":"wfwf",
  "vendorContactNo":3245353}]
```

i have already used

```
$http.get('/vendor',{
                    headers: AuthServ.getAuthHeader()
                })
                .success(function (data, status) {

                    var x = ref.child("vendors");
                    x.remove();
                    angular.forEach(data,function(value, key){
                        x.push({
                            vendorName : value.vendorName
                        })
                    })
```

But i want it without foreach for better performance.
can anybody suggest .Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. But if you want to bulk-set the data, you can simply do `x.set(data)`

Comment: yes i want to set all the backend data in firebase but x.set(data) not working.

Comment: "not working" is rather vague. Please show the code that doesn't work, explain what you expect it to do and describe what it does. Better yet: set up a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem.